# Row Count by relational table and filter by date laravel

Tags: laravel, database, count, sql-order-by, relational

I have offer table and report table I and report table have offer_id table. offer to report table relation on to many, I count reports table row by offer table by desc

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official documentation about counting on relationships:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models